# When should I ask users of a mobile app to login?

Tags: user-expectation, best-practice

Is it better to let user use the application to an extent and then ask to login after using application after some browsing? or is it better to get user info(login) at first. I am seeking the solutions for a best practice point of view not from a technical point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to something called [lazy registration](http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/LazyRegistration).

In lazy registration you do not ask the user to register until she wants to do an action that *requires* an account, such as the following:

- Providing personal information
- Paying
- Saving work
- Adding contacts
- Subscribing
- Favoriting

Answer (score 2):

It depends - but, most of the time, I would prompt users to create an account before trying out the product.

1. Allows you to send nurturing emails to bring users back to your application.
2. You can get a better sense of your target users.

That being said, I would keep the amount of information you collect minimal, maybe just *Email Address* and *Password*.

Even more frictionless, try social sign-in via Google, FB, Twitter, etc.

Comment: Unless the app already has some branding and people really wants to use it (for any reason: productivity, status, word of mouth, whatever) this is most likely a sure path for many users to abandon the journey. Only test will tell how many people will abandon at login screen, but believe me I have seen many apps fail because of this

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the exact case my general idea is:

I believe it is probably better to let the user see what is your app offering from the first moment. Then once you got the user attention you can ask him to register.

Otherwise you will only make some users go away, **why would they give you any personal information without understanding what are you offering and how can they benefit from it?**

Answer (score 1):

### It depends on what your app does

For a purely online service such as Facebook or Twitter, it makes sense to ask the user to make an account first since they must have an account to meaningfully interact with the service.

From the way you described the app's behavior, it sounds like there is significant offline capabilities and an online capabilities too. I would ask a user to create an account when they want the online features but not before.

Another way you could do this is to prompt for login/account creation on the landing page but include a "I'm just looking. I'll create an account later" button. When an unregistered user wants to use an online function, prompt them again to register.

Further, I would do a little A/B testing, if possible, to see whether people are more likely to register if they hit the "I'm just looking button" vs someone who is just asked to register on app launch.